# find a and b F(x) , g(x)

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Functional

$F(x)=(x^2-x+1)Q(x)+x-1$

$G(x)=(x^2-x+1)T(x)+x+1$

$F(x).G(x)=(x^2-x+1)H(x)+ax+b$

find a and b

Comment: As you can see from the above comments, your tone is not very well-received here, you should edit your question to make it suitable for general discourse.

Comment: Hint: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of the quadratic.  Then $F(\alpha)G(\alpha)=\alpha^2-1$. Similar for $\beta$. That should be enough to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Please tell solutions

Comment: Sorry about the choice of letters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, too close to $a$ and $b$. Use other names.

Comment: @all: It would help a lot if you indicated what you had tried. My suggested approach uses complex numbers. There is probably a more elementary way.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the first thing that came to mind. Excessively fancy, but I am too lazy to find another way. **Added**: As the answer by Ng Chung Tak shows, the answer below is indeed wildly overcomplicated. But it may amuse people.

Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be the roots of $x^2-x+1$. Then $F(\sigma)=\sigma-1$ and $F(\tau)=\tau-1$.

Similarly, $G(\sigma)=\sigma+1$ and $G(\tau)=\tau+1$.

So $FG$ evaluated at $\sigma$ is $\sigma^2-1$. This is $a\sigma+b$.

Similarly, $\tau^2-1=a\tau+b$.

Subtract. We get $\sigma^2-\tau^2=a(\sigma-\tau)$. Thus $a=\sigma+\tau=1$ since the sum of the roots of the quadratic is $1$.

Now we can find $b$. It is perhaps easiest to note that $\sigma^2-1=\sigma+b$, so $\sigma^2-\sigma-1=b$. But $\sigma^2-\sigma=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$x^2-1 \equiv (x^2-x+1)+x-2$$

Comment: Nice and simple! Makes my way look enormously convoluted.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, your way would work well when it had real roots.

Comment: My way is always worse for this type of problem. You used the basic fact that if $F(x)\equiv p(x)\pmod{m(x)}$ and $G(x)\equiv q(x)$, then $(FG)(x)\equiv p(x)q(x)$.